# Is there any way to run async await inside async.eachSeries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Is there any way to run `async` `await` inside `async.eachSeries` and `async.forEach` function?

I have tried `async` `await` function

```
async.eachSeries(itemArr, async (item, loop) => {
    await DB.count({ duration: item.duration, service: item.service}); // This is not working
    // Adding more logic
});
```

But `await` is not working.

Comment: Did you try to pass the callback as an async function?

Comment: @MihailFeraru No, I am not passing callback as an `async` function.

Answer (score 2):

The `eachSeries` function applies iteratee to each item in series. If you still want to use `await` inside the iteratee, you should make it an `async` function.

```
async.eachSeries(itemArr, async (item, loop) => {
    await DB.count({ duration: item.duration, service: item.service});  working
    // Adding more logic
});
```